# Unable to see data option in PowerBI desktop

Tags: powerbi

I am unable to see the data option, that shows data in the tabular form, once i use my datasourece as PowerBI Shared/Published Dataset.

[image: PowerBI screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: It will not show the tables when connected to the dataset in live connection mode

Comment: is there any way to show when connected to shared dataset?

Comment: No, when you connect to a shared dataset it is in live connection mode, it should indicate that in the bottom left of the report designer. It will only show in import or direct query mode